# Error after converting create-react-app to Gatsby. WEBPACK: Browser queries must be an array or string. Got object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, gatsby, postcss

I am converting my create-react-app to Gatsby. To do this, I took my existing project and did npm install gatsby, installed `gatsby-cli`, and then copied over the changes in project structure from a fresh Gatsby site. Then, I moved my App.js into src/pages/index.js. I ended up deleting the gatsby-config.js I copied from a site created by `gatsby new` because I didn't know how to install the `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet` plugin. I don't know if the plugins specified by gatsby-config.js are required to make the site work.

This project implements a circular progress bar using react-circular-progressbar. When attempting to build my app using `gatsby build`, I get this error:

```
Unknown error from PostCSS plugin. Your current PostCSS version is 6.0.23, but autoprefixer uses 7.0.26. Perhaps this is the source of the error below.


 ERROR #98123  WEBPACK

Generating development JavaScript bundle failed

Browser queries must be an array or string. Got object.

File: node_modules/react-circular-progressbar/dist/styles.css
```

I updated PostCSS to 7.0.26 using `npm i postcss` but it still says I'm on the old version.

You can see this error if you checkout this [link](https://github.com/caseykey/caseykey.github.io/tree/circular-error).
I'm not sure what a browser query is, but I checked the styles.css file referenced in the error and the only things I am seeing are class styles and then this browser specific style:
`-webkit-transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.5s ease 0s;` Deleting this line doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gatsby-config.js` is one of the essential [Gatsby configuration files](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/api-files-gatsby-config/). Any debugging without addings this file back is bound to be hopeless.

Copy the empty `gatsby-config.js` from the [official documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/api-files-gatsby-config/#plugins) and add the PostCSS plugin as described in the [documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/post-css/). Rerun npm or yarn. Run `gatsby clean` and then `gatsby develop`.

The error is most likely caused by a missing source or configuration files that a POSTCSS plugin should provide and solve easily.

Does your site work now?

Comment: What do you mean by rerun npm?

Comment: Do I have to reinstall all the plugins I installed via npm using gatsby now, or is there a way I can migrate them from package.json into gatsby-config?

Comment: The site now builds after I followed your instructions and also added a postcss.config.js file in the root project directory as specified in the Gatsby PostCSS documentation.